# Python bcrypt package on Heroku gives AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ffi'

Tags: python, heroku, flask, bcrypt

I'm having a problem using bcrypt with my Flask application on Heroku. When I deploy to Heroku and go to the login route I get 500 Internal server error.  It works correctly locally.  How do I get the bcrypt package working on Heroku?

```
ERROR in app: Exception on /login [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 477, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 587, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/app.py", line 196, in post
    elif bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_bcrypt.py", line 193, in check_password_hash
    return safe_str_cmp(bcrypt.hashpw(password, pw_hash), pw_hash)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 82, in hashpw
    hashed = _bcrypt.ffi.new("char[]", 128)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ffi'
```

Answer (score 7):

I encountered a similar issue. Here is a copy of the last part of my stack trace:

```
  self.password = User.hashed_password(password) 
File "/app/application/models.py", line 16, in hashed_password 
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_bcrypt.py", line 163, in generate_password_hash 
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 50, in gensalt 
  output = _bcrypt.ffi.new("unsigned char[]", 30) 
AttributeError: module 'bcrypt._bcrypt' has no attribute 'ffi'
```

I'm wondering if this issue is particular to Heroku. I was using some existing Flask boilerplate. But this issue with Bcrypt has also happened to me in previous projects when using a (different) boilerplate Flask project on Heroku.

**Possible Solution 1**

Play around with different dependency combinations. In one case, the issue went away when I included `cryptography` in my `requirements.txt`. But as Jean Silva had mentioned in this thread, it is possible that dependencies could be in conflict. So you might want to play with different combinations until something works.

**Possible Solution 2**

If using Flask, try having the `werkzeug.security` package/module to hash / check hashes as opposed to using the `bcrypt` package directly. In example below in my `models.py`, commenting out such lines and adding new ones solved the issue for me.

```
# from index import db, bcrypt
from index import db
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.active = True
        self.password = User.hashed_password(password)

    @staticmethod
    def hashed_password(password):
        # return bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
        return generate_password_hash(password)

    @staticmethod
    def get_user_with_email_and_password(email, password):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        # if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
        if user and check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            return user
        else:
            return None
```

Answer (score 5):

By installing bcrypt==3.1.2 it's work for me

```
pip install bcrypt==3.1.2
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution, I was using the following packages: `bcrypt`, `flask_bcrypt` and `py-crypt`. So I uninstall the `py-bcrypt`, probably this package was in conflict with `bcrypt` package.

```
pip uninstall py-bcrypt
```

Comment: are you aware of any other packages that could be causing this issue? I do not have `py-bcrypt` installed but am also facing the same error message. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

uninstall both py-bcrypt and bcrypt is you installed it previously.
Then install py-bcrypt afresh.

`pip install py-bcrypt`

Comment: Ya, this worked for me. I installed `bcrypt` first, didn't work as I wanted, then added `py-bcrypt` and removed `bcrypt`. I guess it didn't like that, but once I uninstalled and reinstalled `py-bcrypt`, it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3.7, below is the sequence of commands that resolved the error in my case:

```
pip uninstall py-bcrypt && pip uninstall flask-bcrypt && pip uninstall bcrypt && pip install flask-bcrypt
```