# Password hashing error in Django 3.1.4 - hashers.py

Tags: python, django

Today when I started my Django project I got error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

After research I figured out that it is problem in hashers.py file in django.contrib.auth library. Somehow it stopped working I am not sure if it is after Django update or anything else.
This error appears when app is registering new User or when i try to Login existing User.

My code to login user looks like this (function is called in views.py):

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def login_user(request):
    email = request.data.get("email")
    password = request.data.get("password")
    user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
```

JSON Request that comes from API looks like this:

```
{
"email": "example@example.com",
"password":"mypassword"
}
```

code to register user like this (it is called in serializer.py):

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
            phone=validated_data.get('phone', None)
        )
        return user
```

also here is my User Model class:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
email = models.EmailField(_('email'), unique=True)
username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=255, blank=True)
phone = PhoneField(_('phone'), blank=True)
status = models.IntegerField(_('status'), default=11)
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

class Meta:
    # db_table = 'label_user'
    verbose_name = _('user')
    verbose_name_plural = _('users')

def get_full_name(self):
    '''
    Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
    '''
    full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
    return full_name.strip()

def get_short_name(self):
    '''
    Returns the short name for the user.
    '''
    return self.first_name

def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
    '''
    Sends an email to this User.
    '''
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

What I tried:

1. Downgrade django but it does not helped.
2. Update Python packages also does not make any change.
3. create new Python venv and install all packages again with and without --no-cache-dir flag enabled

Workaround that I found:

I figured out that when I open hashers.py file in place where app throws error and change line from:

```
 return "%s$%s" % (self.algorithm, data.decode('ascii'))
```

to:

```
return "%s$%s" % (self.algorithm, data)
```

it works fine.

Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: Where do you call authenticate and what is the content of the password variable and type? Same goes for the validated_data['password']

Comment: @andreihondrari I've updated post.

Comment: Did you compare bcrypt libraries after upgrade? Looks like you use BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher and docstr for this hasher says `Please be warned that this library depends on native C code and might cause portability issues.` What Django version did you use before btw?

Comment: @SergeiZherevchuk I did not compared bcrypt versions but I used django 3.0.7 before update to 3.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I updated ubuntu packages and pip packages with:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
pip-review --local --interactive
```

Then I figured out that error message changed:

> 'bcrypt' object has no attribute 'ffi'

I found [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854768/flask-bcrypt-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-ffi-deployed) and check if I have multiple bcrypt libraries installed. After execude commands:

```
pip3 list | grep bcrypt
```

I realized that I have `bcrypt` package and `py-bcrypt`. I uninstalled py-bcrypt and everything started working.

Another option that also worked for me was to change hashing library. Just like @Sergei Zherevchuk mentioned in comment:

> Please be warned that this library depends on native C code and might cause portability issues.

I changed hash library in settings.py, from:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
      'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher'
]
```

to (for example):

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
      'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher'
]
```

Last step that I did was to install Argon2 django library with command:

```
pip3 install django[argon2]
```

And everything is working with different hashing algorithm.