# Airflow on Heroku keeps running into bcrypt error

Tags: python, heroku, bcrypt, ffi, airflow

Has anyone run into the following error while trying to get Airflow running on a remote Heroku server? My airflow webserver runs fine but I am trying to add security to the service. I am following the example of creating a user at https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/security.html. However when I try to create a password:

```
user.password = 'set_the_password'
```

I get an error saying.

```
AttributeError: module 'bcrypt._bcrypt' has no attribute 'ffi'
```

Running pip freeze reveals that I have not only bcrypt but also

```
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
bcrypt==3.1.3
py-bcrypt==0.4
cryptography==1.8.1
cffi==1.10.0
```

I am suspecting that there are some C dependencies that are getting lost in the requirements.txt. I am know this maybe a repeat of [Python bcrypt package on Heroku gives AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ffi'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980976/python-bcrypt-package-on-heroku-gives-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-att), but I am not looking to monkey patch and I have crytography as a library included. Any help would be appreciated!